# Referring a dict and making a new dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows.(dict_Xero_Profile)

```
dict_Xero_Profile ={'a': ['Demo'], 
                    'b': ['PMS'],
                    'c' : ['All']}
```

And I have a list as follows.

```
x = ['Demo','PMS']
```

I need to create below new dict  by filtering list element from dict_Xero_Profile.

```
new_dict = {'a': ['Demo'], 'b': ['PMS']}
```

Can someone adviseon this.And also to practice this basic things where I can start.(Good place I can practice simple problems)

Comment: `[(k, v[0]) for (k, v) in dict_Xero_Profile.items() if any(y in v for y in x)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
dict_Xero_Profile ={'a': ['Demo'], 
                    'b': ['PMS'],
                    'c' : ['All'],}

x = ['Demo','PMS']
res = {k: l for k, l in dict_Xero_Profile.items() if ''.join(l) in x}
print(res)
```

output

```
{'a': ['Demo'], 'b': ['PMS']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to filter items that their value is included in `x` :

```
new_dict = {k:v for k,v in dict_Xero_Profile.items() if v[0] in x}
```

the result of `new_dict` will be:

```
{'a': ['Demo'], 'b': ['PMS']}
```